# what is meant by trailing space and what's the difference between it and a blank?

Tags: c++, c

What is meant by trailing space and what's the difference between it and a blank ?
I saw an exercise where there is a note about trailing space.

I didn't see the problem on that because `cin` can ignore those spaces and catch only numbers ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Trailing space is all *whitespace* located at the end of a line, without any other characters following it. This includes spaces (what you called a blank) as well as tabs `\t`, carriage returns `\r`, etc. There are 25 unicode characters that are considered whitespace, which are listed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

Comment: I personally would want to distinguish between trailing _whitespace_ and trailing _spaces_, but perhaps that's a question of termnology.

Comment: That is a good point. It will depend on your specific application what trailing space should be removed. This may just be spaces and tabs.

Comment: when we use for instance in C++ the function cin for input they will be ignored am I right ?

Comment: Yes, `cin` will ignore trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks !
This is the problem where I come across that term ! 
http://www.codechef.com/MARCH14/problems/PROSUM/

Comment: How can `cin` "... ignore trailing whitespace" then even determine the end-of-the-line if it ignores white-spaces as white-space includes `'\n'`?  Is not white-space relevance a issue of the function that uses `cin` and not of `cin` itself?

Answer (score 4):

> what's the difference between [trailing space] and a blank?

A blank at the end of a line is a trailing space.
A blank between characters (or words, or digits) is not a trailing space.

> what is meant by trailing space?

Trailing space became a challenge for me for something I was trying to code.  The challenge inspired me to create the following utility routines.  For this particular effort, I defined "trailing space" as any "white space" at the end of a line.  (Yes, I also created versions of this function for leading white space, and extra white space (more than 1 white space character in the middle of the line.)

```
const char* DTB::whitespaces = "\t\n\v\f\r ";
//                               0 1 2 3 4 5
// 0)tab, 1)newline, 2)vertical tab, 3)formfeed, 4)return, 5)space,


void DTB::trimTrailingWhiteSpace(std::string& s)
{
   do // poor man's try block
   {
      if(0 == s.size())  break;  // nothing to trim, not an error or warning

      // search from end of s until no char of 'whitespaces' is found
      size_t found = s.find_last_not_of(DTB::whitespaces);

      if(std::string::npos == found)  // none found, so s is all white space
      {
         s.erase(); // erase the 'whitespace' chars, make length 0
         break;
      }

      // found index to last not-whitespace-char
      size_t trailingWhitespacesStart = found + 1; // point to first of trailing whitespace chars
      if(trailingWhitespacesStart < s.size())      // s has some trailing white space
      {
         s.erase(trailingWhitespacesStart); // thru end of s
         break;
      }

   }while(0);

} // void trimTrailingWhiteSpace(std::string& s)
```

Answer (score 3):

A trailing space in programming (as I think you're referring) it's a series of whitespaces at the end of a string or a line.

They can cause some hassle under the following circumstances:

- You might have a string literal spanning multiple lines, in that case it can be tricky to debug a trailing whitespace
- Can slow the development process when you always have to "fix" those by hand when you have to type-append on a line
- Some parsing tools might have problems with them